# Kubeflow: problem with SSL certificate in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow

We installed Kubeflow 1.0 on Kubernetes 1.15.16 (with Azure) and we have an issue with SSL certificate when trying to install pip package in Jupiter Notebook. The same issue also appear when trying to install directly the package from the docker container used for the Notebook Server:

[image]

In order to provide more context about the mentioned issues, here are attached some outputs that contain the errores mentioned within.
Issues found during installation of ‘nose’ package

If we try:

```
 pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ nose
```

Output is:

```
WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.python.org.

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError


Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/nose/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nose (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nose

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/
```

Similar issue also happen using curl:

```
! curl https://pypi.org
```

Output:

```
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'pypi.org'
```

We tried to ignore the SSL verification using

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

But is also raise an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nose (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nose
```

We dont know where to start to solve this...
Any help would be welcome!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got a same exception in kubeflow with Azure.

This command work for me:

```
pip install xgboost -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
```

pypi.douban.com is a chinese mirror url.

But when I go to the next step, I got the same ssl ca error when use kubeflow sdk in python. I'm still finding solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed it is working with this mirror probably because using http instead of https. But as you say, the issue mostly remains.